# Kali Linux 2020.2 Stuck on dragon logo

Tags: kali-linux, oracle-vm-server

I have an installed Kali linux 2020.2 on my Oracle VM

and by mistake I turned my computer OFF when the Oracle was saving the session ...

and now when I'm trying to boot on it get stuck at "the Dragon logo"

[image: the Dragon logo]

What I've tried so far:

- Left it for an hour ... and it always stuck as the image above shows
- I changed the Kernel I tried 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.9.0
- And for grub I tried with splash (delete this value) and quit (change it to non-quit)

**How to fix that boot problem**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @jsotola How to fix that ? The box stuck on that screen for hours how I fix that and login again

Comment: Recreate the VM and start from scratch

Comment: @Panki I need my stuff inside it :(

Comment: Then attach the harddrive to another VM... if you don't know how to do that, you should probably not mess with kali in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution after many research:

Go to CMD (Administrator Privileges)

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and REBOOT

Or

> WooHoo fix for VMware  Device Security/Credential Guard issues
>
> Well Boys and Girls after reading through the release notes for build 17093 in the wee small hours of the night, I have found the
> change point that affects my VMware Workstation VM's causing them not
> to work,  it is the Core Isolation settings under Device Security
> under windows security (new name for windows defender page) in
> settings.  By default it is turned on, however when I turned it off
> and restarted my pc all my VMware VM's resumed working correctly.
> Perhaps a by device option could be incorporated in the next build to
> allow us to test individual devices / Apps responses to allow the core
> isolation to be on or off per device or App as required .

```
From the Start Menu: **Windows Defender Security Centre > Device Security > Core Isolation**.
```

**Attribution:**
[WooHoo fix for VMware](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2753727#messageview_0)

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- Control Panel
- Program and Features
- (On the left pane) Turn windows feature on
- Uncheck - Windows Hypervisor Program
  and then reboot the system. If it says or not, rebooting is necessary. Then launch kali, and you are good to go!