# Kali Linux OVA stuck on booting

Tags: kali-linux, windows, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, amd

I'm trying to use `Kali Linux OVA (version 2020.4)` in the `Virtual Box (version 6.1)`. However, my Kali OVA stuck on the dragon logo for an hour:
[image: kali-stuck-on-dragon-logo]

I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622807/kali-linux-2020-2-stuck-on-dragon-logo) and the solution. However, im using `WSL(Windows subsystem for Linux)` for school work and after I tried to apply `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` the WSL stops working. Does anyone have a solution other than the post above?

My host OS configuration: AMD Ryzen™ 5 3600X, 12 core, 16GB RAM, 512 GB SSD + 1TB HDD, RTX2060S, Windows 10 Home build 19042.

Answer (score 1):

A better question title would be something like "How to enable both VirtualBox and WSL on Windows 10".

I can think of three possible additional workarounds:

- Does your schoolwork require features from WSL2?  If you can use just WSL1 features, you can convert your WSL instance to version 1, and it should be able to run when Hyper-V is disabled.
- Alternatively, although not much better than manually changing it on reboot, you could set up one Windows boot entry that enables Hyper-V for WSL2, and a second one that disables it for Virtual Box.  Full details (along with more information on why VirtualBox and Hyper-V can't co-exist), [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/139405-run-hyper-v-virtualbox-vmware-same-computer.html).
- If you have Windows Pro or higher (or can upgrade cheaply using a student discount, perhaps?) then you should be able to run a Kali VM using the full-blown Hyper-V available in Pro.